# Build Error with Brackets-shell

Tags: adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

I am trying to test out building my app and when I run

```
grunt full-build
```

I get this error

```
Running "build-mac" task
>> ** BUILD FAILED **
>>
>>
>> The following build commands failed:
>>     PhaseScriptExecution Postbuild\ \"Strip\ If\ Needed\" xcodebuild/appshell.build/Release appshell_helper_app.build/Script-27C0F1588A910AFD1BAFF6BD.sh
>> (1 failure)
Warning: Task "build-mac" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Does anyone know how to correct this so I can make sure I have everything ready to go for creating/building apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I was able to get rid of the error by commenting out the call to "strip_save_dsym" from tools/strip_from_xcode line 61ish.  I have no idea if that still creates a proper build, but it does clear out the errors. Here is the link that lead me to this [fix](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=701#p2869).

Comment: Actually, I did the same thing and it has been working fine. Not sure why it is causing an error though. Thanks!